# In C#, what could cause a hosted service to be canceled and what is the best way to recover?

Tags: c#, task, azureservicebus, cancellation-token, asp.net-core-hosted-services

We have a hosted service which transcribes data from the Azure Service Bus to another microservice.  Aside from putting data in a Queue on the service bus, there is no opportunity for a human to interact with this microservice.

Occassionally -- once every few weeks -- the hosted service will suddenly stop working until we restart the server.  Aside from one suspicious log entry in Application Insights, this failure is entirely silent.

The log entry tells us the system failed to connect to the service bus and the task was canceled.  It isn't entirely clear which is the cart and which is the horse (in other words, whether the task was canceled because it could not connect or whether the connection failed because someone/something caused a cancelation).

The service is started in Startup.cs through `ConfigureServices()` by executing `AddRelayService<ServiceBusToSalesforceHandler, LackmannFeedbackDto>(services, meterExchangeFeedbackConfig);` which invokes:

```
    private static IServiceCollection AddRelayService<THandler, TDto>(IServiceCollection service, IMessageConfig queueConfig)
        where THandler : IInboundMessageHandler =>
        service.AddHostedService(provider =>
            ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<HostedRelayService<THandler, TDto>>(
                provider,
                ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<THandler>(provider, queueConfig)
            )
        );
```

HostedRelayService looks like:

```
public class HostedRelayService<THandler, TDto> : IHostedService
    where THandler : IInboundMessageHandler
{
    private readonly IMessageReceiver _serviceBusMessageReceiver;
    private readonly THandler _inboundServiceBusHandler;

    public HostedRelayService(IMessageReceiver serviceBusMessageReceiver, THandler inboundServiceBusHandler)
    {
        _serviceBusMessageReceiver = serviceBusMessageReceiver ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceBusMessageReceiver));
        _inboundServiceBusHandler = inboundServiceBusHandler ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inboundServiceBusHandler));
    }

    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private Task _serviceReference;

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_serviceReference != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Instance is already running.");
        }

        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _serviceReference = _serviceBusMessageReceiver.ReceiveWith<TDto>(_inboundServiceBusHandler, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_serviceReference == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Instance is not already running.");
        }

        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        await _serviceReference.ConfigureAwait(false);

        _cancellationTokenSource = null;
        _serviceReference = null;
    }
}
```

but there is no sensible reason `StopAsync()` should ever be called.

ServiceBusToSalesforceHandler looks like this:

```
public ServiceBusToSalesforceHandler(
            IMessageConfig queueConfig,
            ILogger<ServiceBusToSalesforceHandler> logger,
            ISalesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator salesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator,
            SalesforceContractResolver salesforceContractResolver
        )
    {
        ServiceBusConfig = queueConfig ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queueConfig));
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _salesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator = salesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(salesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator));
        _salesforceContractResolver = salesforceContractResolver ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(salesforceContractResolver));
    }

    public IMessageConfig ServiceBusConfig { get; }

    public async Task<InboundMessageHandlerResult<T, TOriginalMessage>> DoWithValidMessages<T, TOriginalMessage>(
            IList<InboundMessage<T, TOriginalMessage>> validMessages,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken
        )
    {
        InboundMessageHandlerResult<T, TOriginalMessage> queueResult = new();
        IList<ISalesforceRecordable> records = validMessages.Select(message => (ISalesforceRecordable)message.Message)
            .ToList();

        IList<SalesforceRecord> salesforceRecords = records
                .Select(eventBusRecord => ToSalesforceRecord(eventBusRecord))
                .ToList();

        UpsertDataManipulationOptions dmlOptions = GetDmlOptions(records);
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Upserting instances of " + typeof(T) + " to Salesforce Cache.");
            if (await _salesforceCacheAsyncDataManipulator.Upsert(salesforceRecords, dmlOptions, cancellationToken))
            {
                queueResult.MessagesToComplete.AddRange(validMessages);
            }
            else
            {
                queueResult.MessagesToAbandon.AddRange(validMessages);
                _logger.LogError("ERROR: Transcribing to Salesforce Cache Failed.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            queueResult.MessagesToAbandon.AddRange(validMessages);
            _logger.LogError(ex, "ERROR: Transcribing to Salesforce Cache Failed: {@Message}", ex.Message);
        }

        return queueResult;
    }

    private SalesforceRecord ToSalesforceRecord(ISalesforceRecordable eventBusRecord)
    {
        if (eventBusRecord is ISalesforceTargetsModifiable modifiable)
        {
            modifiable.SalesforceContractResolver = _salesforceContractResolver;

            if (ServiceBusConfig is ISalesforceTargetsModifier modifier)
            {
                modifiable.TargetSObjectName = modifier.TargetSObject;
            }
        }

        return eventBusRecord.ToSalesforceRecord();
    }

    private UpsertDataManipulationOptions GetDmlOptions<T>(IList<T> homogenousEventBusRecords) where T : ISalesforceRecordable
    {
        T eventBusRecord = homogenousEventBusRecords.First();
        UpsertDataManipulationOptions options = new() { IgnoreDuplicateIdentifiers = true };

        if (eventBusRecord is IExternallyIdentifiableSalesforceRecordable record)
        {
            options.IdentifierField = (
                    ServiceBusConfig is ISalesforceTargetsModifier modifier
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(modifier.ExternalIdentifierSObjectField)
                )
                ? modifier.ExternalIdentifierSObjectField
                : record.ExternalIdentifierFieldName;
        }

        return options;
    }

    public void DoWithBadMessage<T>(Message badMessage, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        _logger.LogError(
            exception,
            "Message could not serialize to an instance of {@ParameterType}.  Message contained {@Body}",
            typeof(T),
            Encoding.Default.GetString(badMessage.Body)
        );

    public void DoOnFailedConnection(Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        _logger.LogError(
            exception,
            "Failed to connect: {@Message}",
            exception.Message
        );
```

We can tell from the log the method `DoOnFailedConnection()` is being hit.

The log looks like:

```
"timestamp [Local Time]",problemId,handledAt,type,message,assembly,method,outerType,outerMessage,outerAssembly,outerMethod,innermostType,innermostMessage,innermostAssembly,innermostMethod,severityLevel,details,itemType,customDimensions,customMeasurements,"operation_Name","operation_Id","operation_ParentId","operation_SyntheticSource","session_Id","user_Id","user_AuthenticatedId","user_AccountId","application_Version","client_Type","client_Model","client_OS","client_IP","client_City","client_StateOrProvince","client_CountryOrRegion","client_Browser","cloud_RoleName","cloud_RoleInstance",appId,appName,iKey,sdkVersion,itemId,itemCount,"_ResourceId"
"1/22/2022, 2:26:08.641 PM","System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver+<ReceiveMessagesAsyncInternal>d__39.MoveNext",,"System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException",,"Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8","Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver+<ReceiveMessagesAsyncInternal>d__39.MoveNext","System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException","A task was canceled.","System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",,,,,3,"[{""outerId"":""0"",""message"":""A task was canceled."",""type"":""System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException"",""id"":""9055691"",""parsedStack"":[{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw"",""level"":0,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"",""method"":""Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End"",""level"":1,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"",""method"":""Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ReceivingAmqpLink.EndReceiveMessages"",""level"":2,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"",""method"":""Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ReceivingAmqpLink+<>c.<ReceiveMessagesAsync>b__27_1"",""level"":3,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic"",""level"":4,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw"",""level"":5,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess"",""level"":6,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification"",""level"":7,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8"",""method"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver+<ReceiveMessagesAsyncInternal>d__39.MoveNext"",""level"":8,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw"",""level"":9,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess"",""level"":10,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification"",""level"":11,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8"",""method"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver+<>c+<<ReceiveMessagesAsync>b__38_0>d.MoveNext"",""level"":12,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw"",""level"":13,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess"",""level"":14,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification"",""level"":15,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result"",""level"":16,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult"",""level"":17,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8"",""method"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy+<RunOperation>d__21`2.MoveNext"",""level"":18,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw"",""level"":19,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8"",""method"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy+<RunOperation>d__21`2.MoveNext"",""level"":20,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw"",""level"":21,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess"",""level"":22,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification"",""level"":23,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8"",""method"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver+<ReceiveMessagesAsync>d__38.MoveNext"",""level"":24,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw"",""level"":25,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess"",""level"":26,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification"",""level"":27,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8"",""method"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver+<ReceiveMessagesAsync>d__39.MoveNext"",""level"":28,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw"",""level"":29,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess"",""level"":30,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification"",""level"":31,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8"",""method"":""Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver+<ReceiveMessagesAsync>d__38.MoveNext"",""level"":32,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw"",""level"":33,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess"",""level"":34,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification"",""level"":35,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Enpal.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"",""method"":""Enpal.Messaging.AzureServiceBus.ServiceBusMessageReceiver+<Receive>d__6.MoveNext"",""level"":36,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw"",""level"":37,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess"",""level"":38,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"",""method"":""System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification"",""level"":39,""line"":0},{""assembly"":""Enpal.Messaging.ServiceBus, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"",""method"":""Enpal.Messaging.AzureServiceBus.ServiceBusMessageReceiver+<ReceiveMessages>d__5.MoveNext"",""level"":40,""line"":0}],""severityLevel"":""Error""}]",exception,"{""AspNetCoreEnvironment"":""Production"",""AzureWebAppsSiteName"":""azureservicebustosfcachetranscriber"",""SourceContext"":""Enpal.AzureServiceBusToSfCacheTranscriber.Helpers.ServiceBusToSalesforceHandler"",""Message"":""A task was canceled."",""MessageTemplate"":""Failed to connect: {@Message}"",""Application"":""Salesforce cache and sync"",""AzureWebAppsSlotName"":""azureservicebustosfcachetranscriber-ops2-production""}",,,,,,,,,,,PC,,,"0.0.0.0",,,"United States",,,pd1ldwk00003Z,"81284f5c-7785-4e90-b087-a1fcb372abf5","/subscriptions/67022d8c-3c39-447e-93c4-d6748e1a8e4d/resourcegroups/salesforceadapters/providers/microsoft.insights/components/azureservicebustosfcachetranscriber","16642e02-7a53-4bbf-9ee0-f8824e22773f","dotnetc:2.18.0-315","e418acc9-7b86-11ec-a505-00155d087b32",1,"/subscriptions/67022d8c-3c39-447e-93c4-d6748e1a8e4d/resourcegroups/salesforceadapters/providers/microsoft.insights/components/azureservicebustosfcachetranscriber"
```

Is it reasonable to believe with the current solution failing to connect to Azure Service Bus is enough to knock out the entire hosted service?

Is there something I can/should add to the hosted service or the startup to make it restart without human intervention?

Comment: I believe the hosting service is free to send a terminate signal to your application at will (IIS used to recycle apps every 28 hours), but you should have some setting in the hosting configuration to restart the service.

Comment: I would run from cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give status of the listener on the server to see if the listener is still accepting connections on the port being used.  It is possible the connection went to "Time Wait" which means a previous connection did not close properly.

Comment: @Neil, thanks for your response.  Could you please elaborate how I would add a setting in the hosting configuration to restart the server?  What would such a setting look like?  Would I need code to handle this setting or would Azure do it automatically?

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for your response.  Can you please elaborate on this.  I *think* I may be able to figure out how to get to a command line on our service, but I'm not clear how I would interpret the result of `netstat -a`, or even sure which port(s) I should check.

Comment: The Azure Service Bus transport uses ports 5671, 5672, and 443 to communicate with Azure servers. Configure firewall rules to allow outbound traffic through these ports. The legacy Azure Service Bus transport uses ports 9350 to 9354 to communicate with Azure servers.Dec 21, 2021